# Get position of currently instantiated object

Tags: unity

I have Variable Temp which is Vector3. And i have variable next which is of type Transform. In the inespector, i have dragged an empty gameobject to "next".

In my update, i have:

```
temp=new Vector3(Random.Range (dmin, dmax), -3f, 0);
        next.position = next.position + temp;

        GameObject go = Instantiate (pillar,next.position,Quaternion.identity)as GameObject;


        next.position = go.gameObject.GetComponent<Transform> ().position;
```

when i run this, get error that object reference is not set to an instance of an object.
The error is generated by the last line.

I'm just trying to instantiate an object that is at a random distance from the currently instantiated object.

How can i fix this?

Comment: What is the exact text of the error?

Comment: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
GM.Update () (at Assets/GM.cs:29)

Comment: I think the Object is not getting instantiated.

Comment: What  type is `pillar`?

Comment: Pillar is declared Transform. Then i dropped prefab into that field in the indespector.

Comment: Changed it to type GameObject. No error now. But it generates only one object. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
next.position = go.transform.position;
```

Comment: Nope. Same error

Comment: @SanSolo This is the correct answer to the title question. You were just asking the wrong question, which is why this didn't solve your problem.

Comment: @Byte56 Yes, the answer is right for the title. Problem was the object wasn't getting initiated and hence causing the error. This is another way of go.gameObject.GetComponent<Transform>().position i was using.

Comment: I'm saying this is a problem with the way you ask questions. Consider the example, *"How do I move an object? I'm trying but my computer won't turn on"*. You're asking how to do something, the presenting an entirely different problem. A problem that some basic troubleshooting would tell you has nothing to do with the question being asked, so they shouldn't be linked at all. The question you should ask in this situation is why you're getting the null reference exception. And that's a programming question that's not specific to game development.

Answer (score 1):

It worked after i changed type of pillar to GameObject.

Also, my temp had -3f for the ycomponent. So it was getting drawn lower and lower and i couldn't see it.